# How to make desktop web app's mouse/cursor act like touch screen mode in Chrome Dev Tools mobile mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, touch-event

I am some experienced .Net developer but new in reactJS guys..
Now, I have a react app that needs to be used with finger (touch like cursor) in desktop.
So, I need to convert classic mouse to touch screen cursor like in Chrome Dev Tools Mobile scrolling. The user should be able to scroll the content clicking on it and drag down or up, righth or left to scroll.
[Google Chrome Dev Tool Mobile cursor sample Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHvfV.png)  or
[Google Chrome Dev Tool Mobile cursor sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRFF5.png)

I check these solutions :

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events 
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/
https://prototypr.io/post/cross-device-inputs-design-for-touch-vs-mouse/
```

But none of them provides a clear solution to apply to a react page.

*Note:Main point is how to make desktop cursor act like mobile cursor.*

Comment: Are you trying custom cursore? Look at this [https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/)

Comment: No, it is already simple. I need to make use of cursor like finger.  I want to make the mouse behave like chrome developer tolls Mobile Mouse, when you open Google Chrome dev console, and click mobile buton top there, the mouse become grey circle and you can scroll the content like you use your finger..

Comment: Hello, could you please provide what you've got so far so we can help you further with your question? You should checkout this link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: To show what is needed, let me to show you this sample. Here one already tried to imitate same mobile scrolling with mouse click, https://kevinsimper.github.io/yearly-calendar-overview/   but it has some problems when you apply to the aweb. The need is mobile finger experience like Chrome Dev  Toolls mobile cursor.